# Add input field based on drop down list using php variables

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm in the middle of making a simple inventory system for keeping track of equipment going in and out of our doors. The inventory is stored in MYSQL, with a table looking like this: id name storage used location_storage location

This is all fun and games when I create a simple form with PHP, so it stays dynamic with the content from the server. I can update all values with no problem.

But for the sake of simplicity I'm looking into having a drop down menu, with a button, that creates/shows input fields in a form. The reason being is that I will have many rows in my table in the upcoming time. As the forms earlier have been made from server information, I will also need the scripts to be dynamic. Right now I'm stuck thinking about what I should do.

As of now, my code for the bits look like this:

**"Static" PHP form:**

```
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
<?php

//conn stuff 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, storage, used, location FROM inventory";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '  ' . $row["id"]. ' ' . $row["name"]. '<input type="text" name="newamount[' . $row["id"]. ']" />';    
echo '<br>';
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
<input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Check out"/>
<input type="submit" name="checkin" value="Check in"/>

</form>
```

**Check in PHP (check out is identical except for change of + and minus):**

```
if(isset($_POST['sjekkinn'])){

//conn stuff

mysql_select_db( 'experimental' );    
$newamount = $_POST['newamount'];

foreach($newamount as $key => $value){
$sql = "UPDATE inventory ". "SET storage = (storage + $value), used = (used - $value)". "WHERE ID = $key " ;
    if (empty($value)) continue;
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );}


if(! $retval ) {
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully!<br>";
header("Refresh:1");
mysql_close($conn);
}
```

Those are all working great, but I would like to use something like the code below for a neater setup... Anyone got any advice?

**Drop down list generated from MYSQL:**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="selectinventory">

<?php 
//conn stuff

$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
echo '<option value="' . $row["id"]. '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
}
?>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add line">
</form>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I want to stop using the two upper code boxes, and instead use the drop down list to pick lines I would like to appear in a form. Right now the form is "statically" made from php.

By that I mean I would like to insert input fields based on selection. I will look if I can find an example of sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found my own solution.

I ended up using my table-populated drop down list as I showed you in the last code box of the question. What came to my mind was that I could simply use the jQuery show/hide function.

What I did was to make a script that told (in "readable") div 'x' to show and move when option 'x' was selected and button clicked. I will show you my complete code in the end.

That way I could have my input fields each created inside a div from my table (the same that populated the drop down list), so I could manage them easier (probably possible to do it easier - but if it ain't broken, don't fix it).  These were created outside the form. When I then click the previously mentioned button, the div will move inside the form. The next one I select will end up UNDER the previous one, instead of just showing up in table-order.

Feel free to shout any questions!

**Here's the complete code:**

```
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
<select name="selectinventory" id="selectinventory">
    <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>

    <?php 
    //conn stuff

    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM inventory";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    echo '<option value="' . $row["id"]. '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
    }?>

</select>
    <div id="btn">Add line</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            $("#" + $("#selectinventory").val()).show();
            $("#" + $("#selectinventory").val()).appendTo($(".selecteditems"));
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
//conn stuff

$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM inventory";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<div style="display:none" id="' . $row["id"]. '">  ' . $row["id"]. ' ' . $row["name"]. '<input type="text" name="newamount[' . $row["id"]. ']" /><br></div>
';    
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>

<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST" name="isthisthearrayname">
    <div class="selecteditems">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Check out"/>
    <input type="submit" name="checkin" value="Check in"/>
</form>
```